# I am new to PHP and am trying to get a submit button to read an SQL Table

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a visible product list on html. I have gotten it to the point where I had all the products and details showing and a submit button with text box for search at the top that did nothing. I then tried to make the submit button for search work but now it’s only showing the text box and submit button and when a query is searched it doesn’t show anything except the URL updates. I am trying to get it to search through the Description Cell data in table Products but it’s not working properly.
Please help me get the search function to work properly.

Here is the code.

```
`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <title>My First SQL Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shopstyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Products List</h1>
    <?php 
        
        // include some functions from another file.
        include('functions.php');
        
        // if the user provided a search string.
        
        if(isset($_GET['search']))
        {
            $searchString = $_GET['search'];
        }
        
        // if the user did not provide a search string, assume an empty string
        
        else
        {
            $searchString = "";
        }
        
        $SqlSearchString = "%searchString%";
        $safeSearchString = htmlspecialchars($searchString, ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
        
        echo "<form>";
        echo "<input name = 'search' type = 'text' value = '$safeSearchString'/>";
        echo "<input type = 'submit'/>";
        echo "</form>";
        
        // connect to the database using our function (and enable errors, etc)
        $dbh = connectToDatabase();
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Description = ?";
        
        // select all the products.
        $statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $statement ->bindValue(1,$SqlSearchString,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        
        //execute the SQL.
        $statement->execute();

        // get the results
        while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            // Remember that the data in the database could be untrusted data. 
            // so we need to escape the data to make sure its free of evil XSS code.
            $ProductID = htmlspecialchars($row['ProductID'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
            $Price = htmlspecialchars($row['Price'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
            $Description = htmlspecialchars($row['Description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
            
            // output the data in a div with a class of 'productBox' we can apply css to this class.
            echo "<div class = 'productBox'>";
            echo "<img src = '/ProductPictures/$ProductID.jpg' />";
            echo "$Description <br/>";
            echo "$Price <br/>";
            echo "</div> \n";           
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>`
```

I have tried updating my SQL query with no luck and I am not sure where the problem lies since the search worked perfect in the SQL database when I tried Select * From Products where description like %radio% and that worked.

Comment: if you prepare your query you don't need to sanitize your input before.

Comment: also your form has no action and no method defined so you are actually getting an undefined on checking if search is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shuld use like for your parameter and add then % to the variable

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Description LIKE ?";
    
    // select all the products.
    $statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $statement ->bindValue(1,"%".$SqlSearchString."%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Hi NBK, 
Thank you for your input. I have done what you have said and it is still just not showing anything. If you do notice anything else, please let me know.

Comment: Remove $SqlSearchString = "%searchString%";` that sets the variable and wil not take the input

Comment: Hi NBK, thank you for your suggestion. I removed that line and updated the second $statement line to show “%”.$searchString.”%” and that finally did the trick. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Ha. Now I see. I hadn't spotted that OP had written "%searchString%" instead of "%$searchString%". Knew it'd be obvious in the end! Have my upvote. :)

Comment: Also, @NickoToumbas, you should click the tick on this answer to mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Yes haha! Just a simple error!! Thank you!! I have accepted this answer now. Thank you for informing me Keiji :)

Answer (score 1):

> I tried Select * From Products where description like %radio% and that worked.

Your code:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Description = ?
```

You do correctly wrap `$SqlSearchString` in `%` signs before binding it to the parameter, but you used `=` instead of `LIKE` in the query.

Comment: Hi Keiji, thank you for your quick response. The reason I tried to use = is because I tried LIKE previously and was still getting the exact same blank result. Is there anything else that you may have spotted?

Comment: Nope, no idea, sorry. Going to have to have to suggest you just try fiddling around with it. It will probably turn out to be one of those things that's "really obvious once you find it" - programming is full of these.

Comment: You were right. It was an obvious one but only after it was thought through and found.